# Select three tables order by specific table

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have this little problem that I can't resolve. I have three tables that a `SELECT` as the following code:

```
SELECT p.*, c.*, i.* 
FROM produto p, categoria c, imagem i 
WHERE p.categoria_id = c.categoria_id 
    AND p.produto_id = i.produto_id 
GROUP BY(p.produto_id)
```

A product (`produto`) can have infinite images from table images (`imagem`), and I want to list only products with one image (of various) only. The image I want is in the column image_order(`imagem_ordem`) of table images(`imagem`) where there is an order, like 1, 2, 3, et cetera.

I want to select the order 1 (ONE) or more close of this. I tried to put`ORDER BY i.imagem_ordem`, but it's not working. I believe that can be a `JOIN` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want but this query will return every product with one image

```
SELECT p.*, c.*, i.* 
FROM produto p, categoria c, imagem i 
WHERE p.categoria_id = c.categoria_id 
    AND p.produto_id = i.produto_id 
GROUP BY(p.produto_id)
HAVING COUNT(i.*)=1
```

Comment: Yes, the QUERY already return one image for product but i want to get the image with image_order (column with INT numbers) more closest of 1 (ONE). You get that ? Can you help?